# How can you filter mail.info from syslog?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

How do I filter mail.info from /var/log/syslog (rsyslog.conf/Debian) while keeping messages greater than or equal to mail.warn?

I've tried just about every different variation of appending and prepending different combinations of `mail, mail.info, mail.!info, mail.*, mail.warn, mail.!warn`, but apparently the [docs](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf.html) are smarter than me.

Currently I'm at this, but alas, she's a no-go:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none;mail.warn,mail.!info -/var/log/syslog
```

**Edit:** I'm having a really hard time understanding the semicolon delimeter and how it "restricts" previous entries.

Comment: Seems like a lot of legit questions I see on serverfault lately have downvotes from the community for no apparent reason.

Comment: You aren't the only one to notice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [`man rsyslog.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyslog.conf) page:

> Rsyslogd has a syntax extension to the original BSD source, that makes
>   its use more intuitively. You may precede every priority with an
>   equals sign (`=`) to specify only this single priority and not any of
>   the above. You may also (both is valid, too) precede the priority with
>   an exclamation mark (`!`) to ignore all that priorities, either exact
>   this one or this and any higher priority. If you use both extensions
>   than the exclamation mark must occur before the equals sign, just use
>   it intuitively.

So `mail.!info` means that you are ignoring `info` priority and any higher priority. Try this:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none;mail.warn,mail.!=info -/var/log/syslog
```

Comment: For completeness, and something that I needed, this will prevent *all* mail log entries going into syslog: `*.*;auth,authpriv.none;mail.!* -/var/log/syslog`

Comment: @Synchro `*.*;auth,authpriv,mail.none -/var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple of other variations to quanta's answer that also seem to work. I have an idea of why they work, but I'm not confident enough with rsyslog.conf's delimeters and operators to be able to say for sure. Hopefully they help someone else.

One.

```
*.*;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    mail.!info,mail.warn     -/var/log/syslog
```

Two.

```
*.*;\
    mail.none;\
    mail.error;\
    auth,authpriv.none       -/var/log/syslog
```

Any comments on these from someone who knows better would be welcome.